# PostGraphile subscriptions - what does "topic" refer to?

Tags: graphql, relay, postgraphile

I'm using PgPubsub and I'm trying to get my head around `listen` and `topic*:""` vis-a-vis what to put there.

For example, let's say I have a `<PostList>` component that renders a list of `<Post>` and I want to update the list when a Post is created or deleted.

I'm not sure how to structure my subscription so I'm listening for changes to PostList. Here's a screenshot of my GraphiQL:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [pubsub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) (publish-subscribe), messages are published to a "topic" and you can subscribe to that topic to receive the messages that are published there.

You appear to be using the ["simple subscriptions"](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/subscriptions/#simple-subscriptions) functionality in PostGraphile, so I'll answer assuming that's the case.

With the subscription `listen(topic: "whatGoesHere?")` you have, you need to broadcast to the `postgraphile:whatGoesHere?` topic to trigger a subscription event. You can do this by issuing the SQL statement `NOTIFY "postgraphile:whatGoesHere?", '{"ok": true}';`. You can do this with `psql`:

```
$ psql your_database_here
[your_database_here] # NOTIFY "postgraphile:whatGoesHere?", '{"ok": true}';
NOTIFY
[your_database_here] #
```

Assuming your GraphQL subscription is running, this should cause the selection set to be evaluated and the results to be sent to GraphiQL.

You'll probably want to fire this `NOTIFY` statement from a function or trigger; you can read more about that in the [PostGraphile Subscriptions documentation](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/subscriptions/).

Comment: Thank you sir. Yes, I am using simple simple subscriptions because when I set it to false and started the app, the Subscription Type disappears from my schema and I get `"Schema is not configured for subscriptions"` in GraphiQL. 

Honestly, I'm so new fullstack development I don't even know if I need pubsub because I'm using Relay. My `post` table is updating fine when I add or delete posts but now I'm just trying to update the UI in real time without having to refresh the page.

Comment: Hello Krik, can you help me with subscription  setup with postgraphile. I just want to create simple event subscribe & listen by multiple users, based on who subscribed it.

If you have any references , please provide me.
Thank you.